# sitecore dynamically content does not update when caching is setup

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 and I have a dynamically breadcrumb and the cache settings when rendering the view:

```cs
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering(RenderIds.Breadcrumbs, new {Cacheable = true, Cache_VaryByData = true, Cache_VaryByUrl = true, Cache_VaryByParameters = true, Cache_VaryByQueryString = true })
```

Also the cache settings are setup in Sitecore on the rendering. 
The issue is that when I access the same item coming from different paths the breadcrumb is not being updated and shows a cached path depending for what got there first. After a while it gets updated, but will fail when I go to the item through another path.

I have removed the caching settings from the view and it looks to work correctly. 
Any idea why this is happening or if I should not use caching on dynamically generated content?

Comment: Is this code present in a Layout or in a rendering?

Comment: Can you provide the caching settings you have on the rendering definition in Sitecore?

Comment: It's in a rendering. The boxes were ticked on : Cacheable , Clear on Index Update, Vary By Data, Vary By Parm, Vary By Query String

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to known product bug in Sitecore 8.0/8.1 which incorrectly handles in-line cache settings.

See this blog post for more info - https://vladimirhil.com/2016/02/28/html-sitecore-renderingpathorid-does-not-apply-varyby-settings/